# Cannot rename table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbctemplate

I have a strange case:
It works:

```
rename table `test` to `test3`
```

but this does not work:

```
rename table `test` to `test1`
```

> Error on rename of (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
>   formed)

UPDATE:

I set:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

I do not have Foreign Keys

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `test` ( `agglomeration_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `carpark_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `numer_urzadzenia` char(3) NOT NULL,  
                      `payments_zone` char(1) DEFAULT NULL, `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, `time_stamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,   
                      `resource_uri` char(200) DEFAULT NULL, `test` int(1) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`test`) ) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Does the table have a foreign key constraint named 'test1' ?

Comment: Add the foreign keys related to this table please

Answer (score 0):

You added a foreign key to an column of the test table, so that means that you need to drop the constraints before you rename it, or maybe deactivate the foreign key constraints and after that rename it.

for **MySQL** try :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;  --> Temporary disables foreign key constraints
```

for **SQL** try:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"   --> Disable foreign key constraints
```

Comment: The exact query worked in my MySQL. I wrote the table names without quotes.

Comment: Im talking about the queries of creating the table and than renaming it.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(constraint_name) 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE constraint_schema = 'test1' 
ORDER BY constraint_name ASC;

Comment: Check if you have any constraints on your database. If you find on for your test drop it